# Simplest/quickest way of 'rendering' view file in PHP

Tags: php, templates

Lets say i have a simple view file called MyView.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$title?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
                    <?=$cotent?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i have a method in my code called `render()`:

```
<?
function render($data)
{

}
?>
```

I need to call `MyView.php` from there and pass `$title` and `$cotent` variables to it.

I know that there is a way of doing that by just replacing `<title><?=$title?></title>` to, lets say, `<title>{TITLE}</title>` and then in `render($data)` just load `MyView.php` into variable and with `preg_replace()` replace all `{BLAH}` with `$blah`.

Is there any other simple way of doing this?

Frameworks shall not be used. Everything from scratch.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `include` that file - PHP is a templating language at heart already.

Comment: If you're insistent on using custom tags (instead of just including like @Rick mentioned), build the replacement array and use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`. Likely to be far more performant.

Comment: @RichBradshaw I can include only PHP classes. Not views. Or it's gonna be a mess.

Comment: @rinchik I don't see how `include file.php` is messier than `file_get_contents('file.php)` with a bunch of `str_replace()`

Comment: @MathieuImbert not `str_replace` but `preg_replace()`. And not a bunch: `  $patterns = array();
  $replacements = array();
  if(is_array($vars)){
   foreach ($vars as $key => $val) {
    $key = strtoupper($key);
    $patterns[] = "/{" . $key . "}/";
    $replacements[] = str_replace('$','\$',$val);   
    }
  }
  $result = @preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$data);`

Comment: There is only 1 reason in my opinion that justifies other solutions then the simple `include`: seperation of responsibilities in a team where one player is allowed to change view files, but not trusted or able to make or judge PHP code. An often heard argument is 'but a view shouldn't be able to change data'. Well, don't do that in views then, and make sure the developers know and follow this. If the developers cannot be trusted not do this, find other developers.

Comment: Well you should use phtml extension for template files so it's easy to distinguish logic file from templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From my personal library:

```
function renderTemplate($tmpl, $__vars=array()) {
    extract($__vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    include($tmpl);
}

renderTemplate("MyView.php", array( "title" => "My Title", "content" => "My Content" ));
```

If you wanted to render to a string, you could modify it a bit:

```
function renderTemplateToString($tmpl, $__vars=array()) {
    ob_start();
    extract($__vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    include($tmpl);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Note that `renderTemplate()` needs to be kept in its own function, even if you're only calling it once: it's using the function's variable scope to keep template variables separate from other variables.

Comment: Could also easily combine that with `ob_` functions to return the content rather than outputting it..

Comment: @rinchik You took the time to comment on your own question and say that you "can include only PHP classes. Not views" and then you +1 an answer that includes views?

Comment: @ColinMorelli yep. you are right :) here `include($tmpl);` is different from `include('MyView.php');`

Comment: @Ben could you please provide a bit more details about ob_ functions? are those ob_start/flush? or a differen ones?

Comment: @rinchik: Added an example of how you'd use output buffering to render to a string.